# PHP/MySQL categories of posts

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I'm trying to create a zone with a selector of categories and for every category to display the posts. I take the categories, and also the posts from a mysql database and I display those on a php page. I also use Bootstrap 4.

Here I explained my problem:
[image: Problem explanation]

My code:

```
<div class="col center_content">
  <div class="categories_buttons">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Choose a category:</small>
    <p>
      <?php
      $category_select = 'SELECT * FROM categories';
      $posts_select = 'SELECT * FROM categories, posts WHERE posts.post_categ_id=categories.categ_id';
      $category_query = $DBcon->query($category_select);
      $category_query2 = $DBcon->query($category_select);
      $posts_query = $DBcon->query($posts_select);
      if(isset($category_query)){
        while($category_row = $category_query->fetch_assoc()){

       ?>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseCategory-<?= $category_row['categ_id'];?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCategory-<?= $category_row['categ_id']; ?>">
      <?= $category_row['categ_name'] ?>
    </button>
  <?php
  }
}
?>
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="clasa_cu_probleme">
    <?php
      if(isset($category_query2)){
        while($category_row2 = $category_query2->fetch_assoc()){
          if(isset($posts_query)){
            while($posts_row = $posts_query->fetch_assoc()){

     ?>
    <div class="collapse_div collapse" id="collapseCategory-<?=$category_row2['categ_id'];?>">
      <div class="card card-block">
        <?php echo $posts_row['post_name'];
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
      }
    }
  }
     ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$posts_query` needs to be updated for each of the categories, so you will have to update it in each iteration of the `$category_row2` loop.  I can't test the solution, but it would look something like this:

```
<div class="col center_content">
  <div class="categories_buttons">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Choose a category:</small>
    <p>
      <?php
      $category_select = 'SELECT * FROM categories';

// this is moved to below
//      $posts_select = 'SELECT * FROM categories, posts WHERE posts.post_categ_id=categories.categ_id';
//      $posts_query = $DBcon->query($posts_select);

      $category_query = $DBcon->query($category_select);
      $category_query2 = $DBcon->query($category_select);
      if(isset($category_query)){
        while($category_row = $category_query->fetch_assoc()){

       ?>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseCategory-<?= $category_row['categ_id'];?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCategory-<?= $category_row['categ_id']; ?>">
      <?= $category_row['categ_name'] ?>
    </button>
  <?php
  }
}
?>
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="clasa_cu_probleme">
    <?php
      if(isset($category_query2)){
        while($category_row2 = $category_query2->fetch_assoc()){

// This is where it gets updated with the new categ_id, then run the query
              $posts_select = 'SELECT * FROM categories, posts WHERE posts.post_categ_id='.category_row2['categ_id'];
          $posts_query = $DBcon->query($posts_select);

          if(isset($posts_query)){
            while($posts_row = $posts_query->fetch_assoc()){

     ?>
    <div class="collapse_div collapse" id="collapseCategory-<?=$category_row2['categ_id'];?>">
      <div class="card card-block">
        <?php echo $posts_row['post_name'];
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
      }
    }
  }
     ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

This is a better solution because you only have to run the category-query one time:

```
<div class="col center_content">
  <div class="categories_buttons">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Choose a category:</small>
    <p>
      <?php
      $category_select = 'SELECT * FROM categories';

// this replaces the single query
      $posts_selects = array()


      $category_query = $DBcon->query($category_select);

      if(isset($category_query)){
        while($category_row = $category_query->fetch_assoc()){

// populate an array with page_queries values for later
$posts_selects[] = 'SELECT * FROM categories, posts WHERE posts.post_categ_id='.category_row['categ_id'];

       ?>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseCategory-<?= $category_row['categ_id'];?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseCategory-<?= $category_row['categ_id']; ?>">
      <?= $category_row['categ_name'] ?>
    </button>
  <?php
  }
}
?>
  </p>
  </div>

  <div class="clasa_cu_probleme">
    <?php
      if(count($posts_selects) != 0){
          foreach($posts_selects as $posts_select)

          $posts_query = $DBcon->query($posts_select);

          if(isset($posts_query)){
            while($posts_row = $posts_query->fetch_assoc()){

     ?>
    <div class="collapse_div collapse" id="collapseCategory-<?=$category_row2['categ_id'];?>">
      <div class="card card-block">
        <?php echo $posts_row['post_name'];
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
      }
    }
  }
     ?>

  </div>
</div>
```